# Should I use screen+stage for every screen in my game?

Tags: java, libgdx, stage

I have been using LibGDX for while now and stages are pretty interesting (at least on my mind).
But I haven't seen any real guide how to use stages like pro.
Now my current project has MainMenuScreen, MainMenuStage,GameScreen, GameStage classes and many more coming.
I have already encountered problems with setting input because of my multi-stage-screen-system. So it would be nice to know if there is any better way to implement screens+stages.

There are multiple topics about using many stages at the same time on screen but I haven't seen any thing for other side.

So is it necessary to use Screen and Stage class for every screen in game  ? Or is there even better way than screen + stage class to display menus and general stuff?

**TD;DR:** Should I use multiple screen and stage classes in game?

P.S. Thanks in advance and sorry if there is spelling mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not used LibGDX but I have had to deal with the same scenario and delt with it different ways.  I found that what works well for me is putting common fields and methods in parent Stages or Screens and then make child Screens and Stages to put fields and methods that are unique to those classes.

For example in a particular application I have a class called AppScreen.  All my screens inherit from it.  I also have another class called PagableScreen which also inherits AppScreen, and I have a few classes that inherit from PagableScreen.  This allows me to put all fields and methods that pertain to PagableScreen sit in one place and do not need to be re-implemented across other classes that require pagable capabilities.

An oppossing design is to use the Decorator pattern, which actually works quite well but can get messy if the problem space is not big enough to warrant it.  With Decorator you create specific features and attributes as add-on classes to particular Screen/Stage, e.g. Decoration classes.  So taking the PagableScreen as an example, I would instead have PagableDecoration, which any screens that require pagable capabilities would decorate themselves with.  This is actual works well in situations where there might be some other decorations you might want to add on.  For example lets say you also have a MenuDecoration which gives a Screen some capabilities for doing a menu screen and now require both Pagable and Menu capabilities.  With the Decorator pattern you can get both in one class, where as with pure inheritence you can only be either PagableScreen or MenuScreen.

But ultimately I do agree that there will be a GameScreen and GameStage and MenuScreen and MenuStage and so forth and so on.  The goal is to make them elegent and possibly small if much of their implementation can be put into a parent class or a decoration.

Comment: So your first suggestion would be to do same way i dealt it but adding one "master" class for screens and stages so actual ones could stay clean as possible?  How about that second way? I don't yet catch how that works.

Comment: Correct.  For the second way, which is called Decorator, you would have to lookup that design pattern.  It is popular and extensively written about but it can be a little bit of a pain to implement.  IMHO, if you can get away with inheritence then do it but please take the time now to learn Decorator because then you will know when and how to switch to Decorator if need be.

Comment: Hmm... Since this is first time i hear about Decorator so I need to look it up.

Answer (score 1):

`Screen`s are ususaly used for parts of your game, which have different tasks.
A `MenuScreen` for example has different tasks then your `GameScreen`, so it should be another `Screen`. Also those gameparts often use different ressources, so using different `Screen`s allows you do load/unload ressources, when switching `Screen`.
So you don't need to use `Screen`s, but it makes things alot easier.
You could have everything inside one `Screen`, but that just makes things more complicated and the code will be harder to read.

You can also have different `Stage` classes for your `Screen`, even though i never created a `Stage` class, but just used the standard `Stage` and added some `Actor`s to it.
Just remember to set the `Stage` of your current `Screen` as your `InputProcessor` or you won't notice inputs.
If you are using `InputMultiplexer`, make sure to unregister your `Stage` inside the `Screen.hide` method, as it shouldn't get inputs anymore.
Also note, that `Scene2D` and it's `Stage` has some disadvantages:
You can't use the MVC-Pattern, as the `Actor`s have a `act` (method which updates the logic) and a `draw` (method which draws the `Actor`). So logic and view are in the same class.
This might work for UI (i like to use `Scene2D` for UI) and simpler games, but in bigger games it might be easier to use something else.

Comment: Yeah i have used screens for displaying different stuff but i also used every time new stage when i chanced display so my screens classes started to look pretty identical and non-existant. That got me wonder if there is any better way to use stages and screens.  At least actor can be disabled from draw cycle but yeah i probbly need to look more about actors and stages when i start to do anything bigger.

Comment: You also mentioned that you haven't used stage-classes. Is there some special reason to this or is it just because you want to draw and do physics at different times? I have used only stage-classes so far and i did all stuff in stage so screen was only there to display stage. Some other disadvantagesthere than draw+physics -thing?

Comment: I am using `Scene2D`, but only for UI. Disadvantages beside the logic+draw-thing are the draw-order. You can not really define, which objects will be drawn first and which one will be drawn last. The object, which are drawn last will overdraw all others. You can only use the z-idx to sort the draw order, but you can't really fix that order.